# Larastan complains about collection methods paramaters after upgrading to Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, phpstan

After upgrading to Laravel 10 I'm having hard times with Larastan errors.

The following code which was perfectly fine until 1 hour ago:

```php
return $this->articleRepository->getDefaultArticles($organizationId)
    ->toBase()
    ->map(function (Article $article) {
        return new Content(
            $article->id,
            $article->title,
            $article->language,
        );
    })
    ->toArray();
```

now gives me the following error:

> Parameter #1 $callback of method Illuminate\Support\Collection<(int|string),Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>::map() expects callable(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, int|string): App\Academy\Content,
> Closure(App\Models\Article): App\Academy\Content given

The repository method has the correct hint:

```php
/**
 * @return Collection<Article>
 */
public function getDefaultArticles(OrganizationId $organizationId): Collection
{
    /** @var Collection<Article> */
    return Article::query()
        ->where('organization_id', $organizationId)
        ->get()
        ->keyBy('id')
        ->values();
}
```

It gives me 115 new errors and most of them are similar to this, related to collection methods like `map` and `reduce`.

The quick solution would be using a temporary variable and add a type hinting:

```php
/** @var Collection<Article> $articles */
$articles = $this->articleRepository
    ->getDefaultArticles($organizationId)
    ->toBase();
```

but I don't want to do it 100 times and even the IDE is complaining that's unnecessary

[image]

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: for the record, I created an issue on laravel framework https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/47986

Comment: Larastan has the same discussion https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/issues/1703

Comment: same discussion on laracasts:  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/larastan-reporting-error-with-collectioneach-method

Comment: the bug report on phpstan https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/9735

Comment: Try  removing Article model from map(function (Article $article) { ...} to map(function ( $article){...}

Comment: I have the same problem on Laravel 9.52.14

it was working fine with phpstan/phpstan:1.10.11
but the problem started on phpstan/phpstan:1.10.12
now the latest available version(phpstan/phpstan:1.10.27) still has this problem

Comment: What is `OrganizationId` type in `getDefaultArticles` method. What will be the expected value for this parameter i.e. string, uuid or something else?

Comment: remove the Article type from the callback of map

Answer (score 1):

The only work around I found so far is to make it in 2 steps with type hinting.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection $result */
$result = $this->articleRepository->getDefaultArticles($organizationId);

return $result->map(function (Article $article) {
    return new Content(
        $article->id,
        $article->title,
        $article->language,
    );
})
->toArray();
```

it does not really help to deal with 115 new errors. But if you would have couple errors, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me was downgrading phpstan:

```
$ composer require phpstan/phpstan:1.10.11 --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/**
* @return Collection<int,Article>
*/
```

for getDefaultArticles php doc type

see this: https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#eloquent-collection-now-requires-2-generic-types

Comment: good finding, but irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Article type from the callback of map :

```
...
->map(function ($article) {
        return new Content(
            $article->id,
            $article->title,
            $article->language,
        );
    })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Static code analysis tools have the possibility to create a baseline file, which contains existing and known errors to be fixed later - either fixed in the code, or with a corresponding update of the parser & inference tools. This baseline is for instance supported in PhpStan/LaraStan or PsalmPHP.

This way you can acknowledge the described inference flaws and continue with focussing again on the actual application logic.

> #### Baseline file
>
> In older codebases it might be hard to spend the time fixing all the code to pass a high PHPStan Level.
>
> To get around this a baseline file can be generated. The baseline file
> will create a configuration file with all of the current errors, so
> new code can be written following a higher standard than the old code.
> (PHPStan Docs)
>
> ```bash
> vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --generate-baseline
> ```

*source: https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan#baseline-file*

Find more details in [PhpStan's The Baseline](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/baseline) section.